# How to play a video on a picture using ARCore and OpenGl [Augmented Image]

Tags: java, video, opengl-es, augmented-reality, arcore

I am working on an app right now which should track an image and play a video loop within the picture once recognised.

The recognition of the picture works fine, as well as the playing of the video.
However, I can not manage to place the video inside the frame of the picture. The video appears outside the picture which I do not want.

Any ideas how I can fix it? I am working based on the Augmented Image Example from Google:
https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/tree/master/samples/augmented_image_java

To play the video I used this tutorial:
https://medium.com/nosort/playing-video-in-arcore-using-openggl-a81ff62f7a6d

This is the code snippet where I set the anchor inside of the class of `AugmentedImageActivity.java` (shortened):

```
  private void drawAugmentedImages(
      Frame frame, float[] projmtx, float[] viewmtx, float[] colorCorrectionRgba) {

    switch (augmentedImage.getTrackingState()) {
    case TRACKING:

      if (movieAnchor != null) {
        if (!viewRenderer.isStarted()) {
          viewRenderer.play("testvideo.mp4", this);
        }

        int scaleFactor = 1;
        float[] modelMatrix = new float[16];

        //Position still wrong
        movieAnchor.getPose().toMatrix(modelMatrix, 0); //hier noch schauen
        viewRenderer.update(modelMatrix); //hier noch schauen

        viewRenderer.draw(viewmtx, projmtx);
```

And this is the `draw()` function where I believe I have to setup the correct position inside `ViewRenderer.java` (Taken from the tutorial):

```
public void draw(float[] cameraView, float[] cameraPerspective) {
    if (done || !prepared) {
        return;
    }
    synchronized (this) {
        if (frameAvailable) {
            videoTexture.updateTexImage();
            frameAvailable = false;

            if (videoTexture != null) {
                videoTexture.getTransformMatrix(mTexCoordTransformationMatrix[0]);
                setVideoDimensions(mTexCoordTransformationMatrix[0]);
                createQuadTextCoord();
            }
        }
    }
    Matrix.multiplyMM(modelView, 0, cameraView, 0, mModelMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(modelViewProjection, 0, cameraPerspective, 0, modelView, 0);

    // ShaderUtil.checkGLError(TAG, "Before draw");

    GLES20.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
    GLES20.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, mTextureId);
    GLES20.glUseProgram(mQuadProgram);


    // Set the vertex positions.
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mQuadPositionParam, COORDS_PER_VERTEX,
            GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, mQuadVertices);

    // Set the texture coordinates.
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mQuadTexCoordParam, TEXCOORDS_PER_VERTEX,
            GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, fillBuffer(VIDEO_QUAD_TEXTCOORDS_TRANSFORMED));

    // Enable vertex arrays
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mQuadPositionParam);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mQuadTexCoordParam);
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mModelViewProjectionUniform, 1, false,
            modelViewProjection, 0);

    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

    // Disable vertex arrays
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mQuadPositionParam);
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mQuadTexCoordParam);

    ShaderUtil.checkGLError(TAG, "Draw");
}
```

I tried to use the `draw()` function from the google example, however I failed to understand it yet and hence to transmit the idea to my problem. Any help would be really appreciated. This is my first experience with ArCore and OpenGl, so sorry if it is a stupid question haha. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

No need anymore. I switched to Sceneform, but thanks anyway.